# Jest test of RootState

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux, jestjs, ts-jest

I have been trying to write a jest Unit test for the following line, and cant figure it out. This is React using Redux

```
export const someState = (state: RootState) => {state.someStore}
```

I have tried everything I can think of, SpyOn, mock, calling directly. I can get it to pass, but when I run a coverage report, this line is never actually tested.

Comment: Can you provide the test coverage report?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
it('some title', () => {
  const state = {
    someState: RootState {
      someStore: {
        data: ''
      }
    }
  }

 expect(someState(state)).toBe(state.someStore)
})
```

Thanks ChatGPT